# Query through multiple navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting confused with my LINQ query and wondering if there is a way I can achieve the following:

A user has a list of liked Categories:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public PersonGender Gender { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [ForeignKey("Suburb")]
        public int SuburbId { get; set; }

        //Information about user preferences
        public ICollection<UserCategory> LikedCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual  Suburb Suburb { get; set; }
    }
```

Where `UserCategory` is defined as follows:

```
public class UserCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser applicationUser { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string applicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And `Category` is:

```
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryFollowers { get; set; }

        public ICollection<EventCategory> EventCategories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserCategory> UserCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally, in my `Events` class I have the following:

```
 public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Is Featured?")]
        public bool isFeatured { get; set; }


        public byte[] EventImage1 { get; set; }
        public byte[] EventImage2 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EventCategory> EventCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserEvent> UserEvents { get; set; }
```

My view requires an object of type `Event`, so I am trying to return a list of Events where the `EventCategory` is contained in the `UserCategory` table. In other words I just want to show events that the user has liked the category for.

**MORE CLARIFICATION**

I am able to filter my events by category from a different function that takes in a hardcoded category Id from the view and this works fine:

```
  //GET:// Browse event by category
        public async Task<IActionResult> BrowseByCategory(int? id, int? alt_id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var eventsContext = _context.Events
                    .Include(m => m.Venue)
                        .ThenInclude(mf => mf.Suburb)
                            .ThenInclude(mc => mc.Constituency)
                                .ThenInclude(md => md.City)
                    .Where(e => e.EventCategories.Any(c => c.Category.ID == id || c.Category.ID == alt_id))
                    .Take(15)
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.StartDate);

                return View("Browse",await eventsContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

I would like to do the exact same as above, but rather than pass in the hardcoded ID queries from the form, I want the query to check the categoryIDs that are saved in the `UserCategory` table. There is no set number of how many `UserCategory` items there are.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And can you explain your question with example?

Comment: @viveknuna I added a bit more detail for clarification. I hope that it helps

Comment: You can use join

Comment: @viveknuna could you please help with an example?